# VFS Global attached old payslips instead of the latest payslips

Tags: standard-visitor-visas, vfs-global, bahamas

I submitted my visit visa application for Bahamas at a VFS office here in India.

I took my last 6 months payslips as one of the proofs of income with me and while collecting the documents the personnel over there handed me the latest 3 months payslips and attached the old 3 months payslips.

Payslips I had : JULY, AUG, SEP, OCT, NOV, DEC

Payslips VFS took : JULY, AUG, SEP

So I want to know if it's going to be a problem for me?

And the other thing is that I mentioned in the application checklist and cover letter that I'm submitting my last 6 months payslips.

Note that my salary bank statements from the last 6 months are attached to the application.

I mailed VFS care regarding this and I'm waiting for their reply.

My question : Is this going to create an issue for me? If yes, any resolution?

Comment: Do not leave the VFS Global office until they have accepted the newest payslips into your package.

Comment: I can only call / email them as of now as visiting VFS requires an appointment apparently.

Comment: Oh, you are not still there? Did you not point out the problem to the person who took your payslips? What did they say?

Comment: I noticed that they took my 'old 3 months' payslips after I noticed the payslips I have after coming home.